# Google Geocoding - Coordinates not being returned into input box

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I've been playing around with the code and I have got something which nearly works but the coordinates don't actually get moved to my input boxes. I have rechecked the code a few times and the console doesn't show an errors so I am a little bit stuck.

Here is my code running:[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sR4GR/13/)

Here is my actual code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true&libraries=places"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://raw.github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie/master/jquery.cookie.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

    // SET COOKIE FOR TESTING   
    $.cookie("country", "UK");

    // GEOCODE RESULT
 function geocode(){

    var GeoCoded = { done: false };
    var input = document.getElementById('loc');
    var options = { types: ['geocode']};
    var country_code = $.cookie('country');
    alert(country_code);
    if (country_code) { options.componentRestrictions= { 'country': country_code }; }
    var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, options);
    $('#searchform').on('submit',function(e){
       if(GeoCoded.done)
            return true;
        e.preventDefault();
        var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        var address = document.getElementById('loc').value;
        $('#searchform input[type="submit"]').attr('disabled',true);
        geocoder.geocode({
            'address': address
        },
        function (results, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                $('#lat').val(results[0].geometry.location.lat());
                $('#lng').val(results[0].geometry.location.lng());
                GeoCoded.done = true;
                alert("Geocoded!");
                $('#searchform').submit();
            } else {
                $('#searchform input[type="submit"]').attr('disabled',false);
                alert("We couldn't find this location")
            }

        });

    });

};      
</script>

<body onload="geocode()">
<form name="searchform">
        <input class="kw" id="keyword" placeholder="Keyword"></input>
        <input id="loc" placeholder="Location" type="text"></input>
        <input type="submit" value="Search" id="search">
        <input class="hidden" id="lat" disabled="true" placeholder="lat"></input>
        <input class="hidden" id="lng" disabled="true" placeholder="lng"></input>
</form>
```

If anyone could point me in the right direction I would be really grateful

Comment: Do you need to specify type=text on the input fields?  Also possibly the disabled=true might be preventing their values being updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. the selector `#searchform` doesn't match your form, the form doesn't have the id-attribute set to .

   Use either the selector `form[name="searchform"]` or set the id of the form to `searchform`
2. githhub is not a CDN, the `jquery.cookie.js` is served with content-type `"text/plain"` and therefore(in some browsers) will be ignored, what results in an error because of undefined `$.cookie`